How can I make frozen yoghurt in a Cuisinart 2-quart freezer bowl-style machine if the mixture is too thick for it to churn?
My mother and I attempted making frozen yoghurt in a freezer bowl that you would put into a freezer and let it freeze for a day or so,but when we put in the yoghurt, which was a Tillamook brand of vanilla yoghurt, it somehow got way too thick, and the machine was unable to churn it at all. I don't know if it was a Greek yoghurt or not, but I knew that Greek yoghurt is generally thicker than non-Greek yoghurt, so I don't know if that could've been the problem. I just checked on-line and it did say it was a creamy yoghurt, so I'm not sure.
How do companies like Menchies or Pink Spoon make these? I know they may use commercial-style machines that might be able to churn more efectively because they have more power, but I'm not sure.
I'd appreciate any help from anyone who has had experience with this, as I always found the process of freezing and churning ice cream/frozen yoghurt to be really fascinating!

Did you add straight yogurt to the bowl? Or what's your recipe? Was it already turning when you did that, or did you put it in, take some time to get organized, and then try to churn after it had sat still for 10 seconds or more?

Pending answers to questions in comments:
It sounds a lot like you put just yogurt into the freezer bowl, which alone will have not nearly enough sugar for reasonable frozen churned dessert. It will freeze way too hard.
If you did not have the machine already churning when you put the yogurt in, it likely froze the layer of yogurt against the sides and bottom of the bowl solid before you attempted to churn it. That frozen layer would prevent the scraper/agitator from being able to turn.
